# generics, reflection, getting access to auto generated code

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm using google's protobuf library that autogenerates code for you.  So if you have a `PersonRequest` for your `Person` object, it'll generate code for you that looks something like

```
PersonRequest.parseFrom(byte[] bytes)
```

So for each of my requests, I have some code that looks like

```
XXXXXRequest.paseFrom(byte[] bytes)
```

What I want to do is write an interface like

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    T parseFrom(byte[] bytes)
}
```

And then after that, I'm not really sure what to do in the implementation.  Does it go like

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    @Override
    T parseFrom(byte[] bytes) {
         return T.parseFrom(bytes);   //  what do I do here?
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to get the object's methods through reflection or what I should do here?

Comment: what does `PersonRequest.parseFrom(byte[] bytes)` return ?

Comment: @davidxxx It returns a PersonRequest.  It basically constructs it from raw bytes.

Comment: Have you looked for a built in way in the library to do what you're trying to do that doesn't depend so much on reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate implementation for your interface, you could reference the parser method directly, and use it to create an instance of the interface:

```
MyInterface<PersonRequest> obj = PersonRequest::parseFrom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each generated class (PersonRequest, OtherClassRequest, etc...) will be a specific class.
So, you should define an implementation by specific generated class.

In these conditions, declaring generics both for interface and the subclass is not required :

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
```

You need generic only for the `MyInterface` interface.
The way which you are declaring it is ok.

Then, subclasses of it should specify the generic type of the parent class that they implement.

For example :

```
public class MyPersonRequestImpl implements MyInterface<PersonRequest> {
    @Override
    PersonRequest parseFrom(byte[] bytes) {
         return PersonRequest.parseFrom(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I want to use reflection is basically every class would look like this for every message type.  All the generated code has PersonRequest.parseFrom(bytes) or OtherRequest.parseFrom(bytes) and I was trying to see if there was a way to have one class do that instead of creating as many classes as I have message types that basically wrap the auto generated code.